# How to compare a variable to see if it's the right class type?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I've been learning Java from scratch again since 2 years of rust, and I was playing around with a simple random generator code. My issue here is that when the user is asked what he wants as his highest die roll, it must be a number (int) class type.

I was trying to create an if statement and compare a variable to its class, rather than letting my IDE stop and show me an error message in a case the user typed letters.

Here is my code (It's the simplest code ever but it's safe to say that I'm new and motivating myself to learn Java again.) :

```
package firstguy;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class randomnum {
  public static void main(String[] args){
      Random dice = new Random();
      Scanner userin = new Scanner(System.in);
      int number;
      int highnum;

      System.out.println("What's the highest roll you want? \n");
      highnum = userin.nextInt();



      for(int counter=1; counter<= highnum; counter++){
          number=  1 + dice.nextInt(highnum);
          System.out.println("This is the number " + number);
        }   
    }
}
```

I want to be able to compare `highnum`, here to see if it stays as the class type int and not a letter. In case a letter or a character is typed, a message should be displayed or the question should be repeated. I've been trying to look for this problem but I keep getting results of comparing two variables of the same class type.

Is there no way to compare a variable to a class type?

Comment: should not have a c++ tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primitive types of Java do not have a class. Their wrapper types do, but your code does not use them.

What you are trying to do is to check end-user input for presence of character combinations that represent an integer vs. everything else. This is relatively easy to do, because `Scanner` provides methods `hasNext...` for various data types. You can use `hasNextInt()` in a loop, discarding the unwanted input, like this:

```
System.out.println("What's the highest roll you want? \n");
while (!userin.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("Please enter an integer.");
    userin.nextLine();
}
// Since we reached this point, userin.hasNextInt() has returned true.
// We are ready to read an integer from the scanner:
highnum = userin.nextInt();
```

Comment: That's interesting. Thank you so much! I now understand hasNext method's usefulness. I was thinking along the lines of an if statement.

Answer (score 1):

`nextInt()` (or most other `nextXYZ` methods, for that matter), throw an [`InputMismatchException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html) if they encounter input that doesn't match their call (e.g., a letter in a `nextInt` call). So one option would be to simply catch it:

```
int highnum;
try {
    highnum = userin.nextInt();
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println ("Wrong input encountered");
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what the "e" is actually? I've only heard about "catching" and error handling but never got a chance to fully understand, but it seems that it's a way of putting up a message rather than simply throwing an exception error in the IDE.

Comment: it is name variable that has type InputMistmatchException

Comment: @OrangeLime yes, `e` the the instance of `InputMismatchException` we're catching. If you wish, you could use it in the `catch` block. E.g.: `System.out.println ("Wrong input encountered. Error: " + e);`

Comment: @Mureinik just curious did I say something different?

Comment: @KickButtowsk nope - just didn't notice your comment when I started typing mine `-)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is not a way to "compare a *variable* to a *class type*", but rather to check a `String` to see if it has the right format.  If you want to see if a `String` consists only of digits, the simplest way is using `matches` and a regular expression:

```
if (inputString.matches("\\d+")) {
    ... the input is valid
} else {
    ... complain
}
```

The regular expression here means "one or more digits".  You could also use `hasNextInt` on a `Scanner`, or use `nextInt` on a `Scanner` and catch exceptions, or use `Integer.parseInt(inputString)` and catch exceptions, just to name a few.

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
  boolean go = true;

 System.out.println("What's the highest roll you want? \n");
      while(go){
      try{
      highnum = userin.nextInt();
      go = false;
     catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("Please type in an integer: ");
         highnum = userin.nextInt();
      }

}
```

Comment: your post  has been flagged as a low quality answer. please add some info or explanation to your post.

Comment: Cool, in case of an error (during the first input), you have to input something new twice.